# Prove that $U_k(n)$ is a subgroup of $U(n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

For each divisor $k\gt 1$ of $n$, let $U_k(n) = \{x \in U(n) ~|~ x\pmod {k} = 1\}$.
Prove that $U_k(n)$ is a subgroup of $U(n)$

($U(n)$ is the group formed by the positive integers less than $n$ that are coprime to $n$)

---

My attempt :
1) $1\equiv 1 \pmod{k}$, so $e\in U_k(n)$

2) $a,b \in U_k(n) \implies ab\equiv 1 \cdot 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{k}$, so $ab \in U_k(n)$

3) Since $\gcd(a,n)=1$ and $k\mid n$, we have $\gcd(a,k)=1$, for all $a\in U(n)$.
Also, since $a^{-1}\in U(n)$, we have $\gcd(a^{-1}, k) = 1$.
I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Appreciate any help. Thanks!

(I'm trying to show $a^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{k}$ at 3rd step )

Comment: To prove that a nonempty subset of a finite (or, more generally, a torsion) group is a subgroup, it is sufficient to prove closure.

Comment: @DerekHolt interestingly, doesn't using the finite subgroup test like this avoid having to use the condition that $k$ divides $n$? I don't see any use of $k$ dividing $n$ in OP's step $2$. Other sources I have seen indicate that we are indeed actually invoking that $k$ divides $n$ when claiming $U_k(n)$ is closed using $(ab)\space \text{ mod k }=(a \text{ mod k })(b\text{ mod k })$

Comment: @upanddownintegrate Try $n=5$, $k=2$. Then $U_k(n) = \{1,3\}$, which is not a subgroup of $U(n)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt No I agree the condition is necessary, I'm just saying that it seems its use is suppressed almost entirely when only using the finite subgroup test. For example: if $x_0\in U_k(n)$ and $x_1\in U_k(n)\implies x_0\text{ mod k}=x_1\text{ mod k}=1$ so $(x_0x_1)\text{ mod k}=(x_0 \text{ mod k})\cdot(x_1\text{ mod k}) = (1\cdot 1)\text{ mod k}=1$. It appears I'm not using the condition that $k$ divides $n$. Am I using it just when I say "if $x_0\in U_k(n)$ and $x_1\in U_k(n)$"?

Comment: @upanddownintegrate But the elements of $U(n)$ are not integers, they are congruence classes modulo $n$. The problem is that, if $k$ does not divide $n$ and $x \in U(n)$, then $x \bmod k$ is not well-defined, and so neither is $U_k(n)$. So really, before you even start on the original problem, you need to check that $U_k(n)$ is well-defined when $k$ divides $n$, i.e. it is independent of the choice of representative of the congruence class of an element of $U(n)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ah okay, I was thinking it was something like that. So I just have to prove if $x_0\text{ mod n} = x_1\text{ mod n}$ and $k$ divides $n$, then $x_0\text{ mod k} = x_1\text{ mod k}$. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Suppose $b \equiv a^{-1} \pmod n$ so that $ab \equiv 1 \pmod n$. Then $n \mid (ab - 1)$. Therefore we have $k \mid n \mid (ab - 1)$ and it follows that $ab \equiv 1 \pmod k$.

Comment: How do i get. $a^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{k}$ from this .Thanks

Comment: @CloudJR The hypothesis is that $a \equiv 1 \pmod k$. Just substitute.

Comment: Sir, how you are allowed to suppose $b \equiv a^{-1} \pmod n$? Further, you didn't consider two elements say $a,b\in U_k(n)$. (From here what we get $a\equiv 1\pmod k$ and $b\equiv 1\pmod k$ but none of this implies $b \equiv a^{-1} \pmod n$

Answer (score 3):

The canonical projection $U(n) \to U(k)$ is a group homomorphism with kernel $U_k(n)$.